# Change xml hex entity into string while loading into marklogic server

Tags: xquery

hexadecimal entity are converted into string while loading XML data into marklogic server please suggest the right solution for this. without using XLST charmap

Comment: Please provide an example with input, output, and expected output. It's not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

There is now way to to this automatically.

In xquery in order to have hexadecimal show up you need to use the &# then the x like this

```
"&#xA9;"
```

You could write a function that looks at the content that your loading in and finds all the hexadecimal already in there and converts them to this format.